# Power BI table visual to get only latest date value

Tags: powerbi, business-intelligence, dax, powerquery

I am very new to Power BI. I have connected mysql database to get data. Am doing search in one filter , based on the searched customer, it will show up the data in table visual. 
But, i stuck to show only the latest date data of a category. 
[image]

If you see in the above image, there are two initial proposal rows. But, i need only one row of initial proposal category which can be differentiate by the date modified column.

to be more clear --> category Id and date_modified are from table1 and inserted_prefix from table two.

now, in the below image. I selected different customer. he had, 3 initial proposal and 5 initial design. So i need only one initial deign and initial proposal which is latest date.

[image]

Please suggest me how can i get only the latest data of each category by using measure or any other way.

Thanks a ton in advance.

Comment: It's probably the easiest to change the sql query to only return latest entry per customer&category. But if you have to use PowerBI, one way is to use query editor ("Home" tab -> "Edit Queries"), Sort table by date ("Home" -> "Sort"), remove duplicates ("Home" -> "Remove Rows" -> "Remove Duplicates") after having selected desired columns (probably both customer and category_id)

Comment: Thank you.. will try as sugested .. am very new to power BI. please don't think this is a silly doubt .. please let me know "where to write sql queries to only return latest entry per customer&category" to get the visual ...

Comment: I cant remove the duplicates directly in table because, each id has initital proposals many ... that id is associated with the customer searched ... so, after searching a customer, whatevr the data is visualized in table, should be distinct in each category with latest date

Comment: I updated my question with one more senario .. please check and suggest me a way to achieve that ... thamks in advance

Comment: To use custom sql query for data import, select "get data" -> expand "advanced" -> fill "SQL statement" with an appropriate one.

Comment: Can't we do using DAX or pwer query or any measure to fit my requirement?

Comment: You can. But it makes more sense to edit your sql query.

Comment: But, the data is related to 5 tables ... i can do in MySQL well .. but i have no idea how to write those queries to fit to my requirement. If possible, can you come to skype or teamviewer . please ... If you can help me in this, it would a million thanks to you ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150798/discussion-between-user6250770-and-user5226582).

Answer (score 0):

I got my requirement.

Just a small tweek in data selections. just make sure to have date modified with Latest. insert_prefix select last as showin in below images.

[image]

[image]