# Power BI: How to Filter a Table To Show Only Most Recent Date For Each Project

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a table to be loaded into Power BI.  There are 3 columns I am concerned with: `Project_Name`, `Document_Name`, `Modified`.
The data in the table is something like this:

```
|   Project_Name   |   Document_Name   |   Modified   |
+------------------+-------------------+--------------+
|   Thing1         |   Apple           |   12/28/2019 |
+------------------+-------------------+--------------+
|   Thing1         |   Orange          |   10/22/2019 |
+------------------+-------------------+--------------+
|   Thing2         |   Banana          |   12/17/2019 |
+------------------+-------------------+--------------+
|   Thing2         |   Banana          |   12/30/2019 |
+------------------+-------------------+--------------+
```

I want to filter the table such that the latest `Modified` date for each `Project_Name` shows, like this:

```
|   Project_Name   |   Document_Name   |   Modified   |
+------------------+-------------------+--------------+
|   Thing1         |   Apple           |   12/28/2019 |
+------------------+-------------------+--------------+
|   Thing2         |   Banana          |   12/30/2019 |
+------------------+-------------------+--------------+
```

I tried adding a column to the table, to add a `True` value to the most recent date for each project.  I pretty much just copied a formula I found on MS forums.  It returned correct results but omitted many records.  This was the formula:

```
IsLatestChangedDateByProjectName = 'Project Documents'[Modified] = CALCULATE(MAX('Project Documents'[Modified]),FILTER(ALL('Project Documents'), 'Project Documents'[ProjectName]=EARLIER('Project Documents'[ProjectName])))
```

I also looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45438288/power-bi-table-visual-to-get-only-latest-date-value) that seemed to be after the same thing - but no real solution was posted.  But it seems that I might have better luck filtering at the table level than calculating a new column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cross-posted this to PowerBI Community and the following worked.  Creating a measure on the table, rather than a filter, that I can use on the visual to effectively filter the rows.  The measure returns a 1 for each latest date per project name.  I can then filter the visual on the measure.

```
Measure = 
VAR maxd =
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( 'Project Documents'[Modified] ),
        ALLSELECTED ( 'Table' ),
        VALUES ( 'Project Documents'[Project_Name] )
    )
RETURN
    IF ( MAX ( 'Project Documents'[Modified] ) = maxd, 1, BLANK () )
```